# How to make long addition, multiplication(Ordinary Polynomial Arithmetic)

Tags: equations

[image]

I can do the division using `polynom` package, but don't do addition, subtraction and multiplication. It may be made using array. But it seems to me hard.

Comment: There are so many alignment points here, it's going to take some work indeed. Personally, I tend to go into plain-TeX-isms (`\ialign` and its ilk) when I run into needs like these. I shall be interested to see if someone comes up with a proper LaTeX solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possible code for multiplication, based on `array`. The first code aligns both powers of the variable and signs, the second code, slightly simpler, aligns only powers of the variable:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{array, multirow, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{array}{*{12}{@{}>{{}}r<{{}}@{}}}
 & & \multirow{2.5}{*}{$ {}\times{} $} & & x^3 & + & x^2 & & & + & 2 \\[1ex]
    & & & & & & x^2 & - & x & + & 1 \\
 \cmidrule[0.6pt](l{-3pt}r{-3pt}){1-11}
 & & & & x^3 & + & x^2 & & & + & 2 \\
 & - & x^4 & - & x^3 & & & - & 2x & & \\
  x^5 & + & x^4 & & & + & 2 x^2\\
\cmidrule[0.6pt](l{-3pt}r{-3pt}){1-11}
 x^5 & & & & & + & 3 x^2 & - & 2x & + & 2 \
 \end{array}
\hspace{4em}
 \begin{array}{*{7}{@{}>{{}}r@{}}}
 & \multirow{2.5}{*}{$ {}\times{} $} & x^3 & + x^2 & & + 2 \\[1ex]
     & & & x^2 & - x & + 1 \\
 \cmidrule[0.6pt](l{-3pt}r{-3pt}){1-6}
  & & x^3 & + x^2 & & + 2 \\
& - x^4 & - x^3 & & - 2x & \\
 x^5 & + x^4 & & + 2 x^2\\
 \cmidrule[0.6pt](l{-3pt}r{-3pt}){1-6}
  x^5 & & & + 3 x^2 & - 2x & + 2
 \end{array} \]

\[ \begin{array}{*{12}{@{}>{{}}r<{{}}@{}}}
 & & \multirow{2.5}{*}{$ {}\times{} $} & & x^3 & + & x^2 & & & + & 2 \\[1ex]
    & & & & & & x^2 & - & x & + & 1 \\
 \cmidrule[0.6pt](l{-3pt}r{-3pt}){1-11}
 & & & & x^3 & + & x^2 & & & + & 2 \\
 & - & x^4 & - & x^3 & & & - & 2x & & \\
  x^5 & + & x^4 & & & + & 2 x^2\\
\cmidrule[0.6pt](l{-3pt}r{-3pt}){1-11}
 x^5 & & & & & + & 3 x^2 & - & 2x & + & 2 \
 \end{array}
\hspace{4em}
 \begin{array}{*{7}{@{}>{{}}r@{}}}
 & \multirow{2.5}{*}{$ {}\times{} $} & x^3 & + x^2 & & + 2 \\[1ex]
     & & & x^2 & - x & + 1 \\
 \cmidrule[0.6pt](l{-3pt}r{-3pt}){1-6}
  & & x^3 & + x^2 & & + 2 \\
& - x^4 & - x^3 & & - 2x & \\
 x^5 & + x^4 & & + 2 x^2\\
 \cmidrule[0.6pt](l{-3pt}r{-3pt}){1-6}
  x^5 & & & + 3 x^2 & - 2x & + 2
 \end{array} \]

 \end{document}
```

[image]